# Postman creates different base64 value than Python's base64 module for unicode passwords - what explains the difference?

Tags: python, postman

I created a random password in python using `os.urandom(10)` which creates a password with unicode values; for example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(10)
'\x8c[A\x91\xf0dq\xb2{\xcc'
```

In my company's ldap tool, I set a user's password as that value.

In Postman, I can create the Basic Authorization header by copy and pasting that value, and **successfully authenticate**.

I tried `requests.HTTPBasicAuth`, but it failled with a `UnicodeDecodeError` From another question, I learned that HTTPBasicAuth doesn't handle unicode values, intentionally. So I tried to do it myself with the base64 module:

```
import requests
import base64
...
encoded = base64.b64encode(username + ':' + password)
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded}
r = requests.post(end_point, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

This however **results in a different base64 encoded value** that the one that Postman builds. The request fails because of authorization.

Additionally, if I copy and paste the base64 encoded value that Postman created into the code, the requests works and I am authorized successfully. This tells me that Postman is successfully doing it.

---

To replicate this yourself, open Postman and create a Basic Auth using username "username" and password "\x8c[A\x91\xf0dq\xb2{\xcc". Postman generates the following 64 encoded string:

```
dXNlcm5hbWU6XHg4Y1tBXHg5MVx4ZjBkcVx4YjJ7XHhjYw==
```

In python, it does the following instead:

```
>>> import base64
>>> username = 'username'
>>> password = '\x8c[A\x91\xf0dq\xb2{\xcc'
>>> base64.b64encode(username + ':' + password)
'dXNlcm5hbWU6jFtBkfBkcbJ7zA=='
```

What accounts for these differences, and how can I get python to generate the same value that Postman does (as Postman generates the correct value?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash in a python string is a special character, `\x` is a hex escape sequence, e.g. `\x8c` is the unicode character for Œ. It looks like you need to explicitly escape the backslash to generate the same value as Postman:

```
>>> password = '\\x8c[A\\x91\\xf0dq\\xb2{\\xcc'
>>> base64.b64encode(username + ':' + password)
'dXNlcm5hbWU6XHg4Y1tBXHg5MVx4ZjBkcVx4YjJ7XHhjYw=='
```

Or make it a raw string:

```
>>> password = r'\x8c[A\x91\xf0dq\xb2{\xcc'
>>> base64.b64encode(username + ':' + password)
'dXNlcm5hbWU6XHg4Y1tBXHg5MVx4ZjBkcVx4YjJ7XHhjYw=='
```

Comment: `\x` is not a Unicode character. That would be `\u`. `\x` denotes a raw byte in hexadecimal and appears in UTF-8 encodings among other places.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, though I'm not quite sure what you mean by the appears statement. `print(repr('\u008c')) -> \x8c`

Answer (score 1):

Your string contains several typical escape sequences. Python will unescape them, unless told otherwise.

To define a string and ignore escape sequences, put an `r` before it. Alternatively you can use double backslashes.

```
text = r'\x00'
text = '\\x00'
```

These will both result in `\x00` and not in the character with ASCII code 0x00 that the escape sequence defines.